# How to display a message for certain HTTP referrers

Tags: php

I'm using the following code to display a message to users based on one website referrer. How can I create multiple entries with multiple different messages? For example, website1.com (referrer) gets message 1, website2.com gets message 2, etc.

```
<?php $referral = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
      $referral = strtolower($referral);
      $referral = explode ("/", $referral);
      $referral = $referral[2];
        if ( $referral == 'google.com'){ ?>
            <div style="font-weight:bold; width:500px; margin:auto; background:white; color:black; text-align:center; font-size:25px">
                <?php echo $referral; ?> is our first partner in trade. <br><br>
            </div>
<?php }; ?>
```

Comment: You're probably better off with `strpos` or `preg_match` in case someone uses **www**.google.com versus just google.com. That said, you've pretty much got the concept covered, so I'm confused as to what the question is.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with strpos or preg_meatch. I don't know PHP very well. And the question is how to add multiple entries. The above is only one entry. A Google referrer gets that message. But I'd like to have 4 referral messages, one for each referral (customized message)